# What is the IF_ELSE basis gate of the processor type Falcon r5.11 on the IBM Quantum platform?

Tags: qiskit, universal-gates, ibm-quantum-devices

I am  master student currently working on a project using the IBMQ platform with qiskit. We are using the available quantum hardware with the processor type Falcon r5.11.

We would like to have a better understanding of the circuits we have composed and how it is really implemented onto the quantum computers. For the processor mentioned above, the basis gates are:

CX, ID, IF_ELSE, RZ, SX, and X.

Since we are able to compose in qiskit any quantum gate, I believe that these 6 gates complete a universal set, and therefore any gate can be composed by a combination of the basis gates above.

Can anyone please tell me what this **IF_ELSE** basis gate is?
What does it look like in matrix form?

Any input is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a quantum gate operation and therefore does not have a unitary gate representation; instead it is an entirely classical operation. The term that IBMQ uses to refer to this circuit type is "dynamic circuits". These operations are supported in [OpenQASM3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.14722). [This youtube video from Qiskit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLMVfImNc0o) gave a clear explanation of how to use dynamic circuits.

The key thing is that the operation is classical, but it can impact the circuit; you can specify if bit `X==1`, do A, otherwise do B. Basic control flow, but the classical computation is based on a classical bit of information. Meaning that you need to measure the state of a qubit, or qubits, into a classical register, and then use this classical conditional to potentially influence how the circuit is executed from that point onward.

Answer (score 1):

The if_else gate would be something like this:

[image: if_else gate]

Where $ |q_1\rangle $ is the condition parameter, $|\lambda\rangle$ the output from the circuit and the controlled-U gates the if ($U_1$) and else ($U_2$) statement

Futhermore, note the matrix of the if_else gate is variable because is dependent of $U_1$ and $U_2$

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Qiskit documentation:

- [`qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.if_else`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.if_else.html) method
- [`qiskit.circuit.controlflow.control_flow.ControlFlowOp.IfElseOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.IfElseOp.html) class

IF_ELSE is a circuit operation which executes a program if a provided condition evaluates to true, and optionally evaluates another program otherwise.